# Get other data from row based on Max value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #TmpTbl
(
 PurchaseId INT
,UserID INT
,InvoiceName VARCHAR(20)
,PaymentDue DATE
,PaymentMade DATE
)

INSERT  INTO #TmpTbl
    SELECT  1
           ,1
           ,'Ef Fee'
           ,'2016-01-01'
           ,'2016-01-02'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  2
           ,1
           ,'Monthly Pmt'
           ,'2016-05-01'
           ,'2016-05-02'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  3
           ,1
           ,'Ef Fee'
           ,'2016-07-26'
           ,NULL

PurchaseId    UserID    InvoiceName    PaymentDue    PaymentMade
    1           1       EF Fee         2016-01-01    2016-01-02
    2           1       Monthly Pmt    2016-05-01    2016-05-02
    3           1       EF Fee         2016-07-26    NULL
```

Sorry for the crappy title.
What I'm needing is to get the `MAX(PaymentDue)` for each user, for invoices that are named `Ef Fee`. Then I need to get the `PaymentMade` value (and usually some other columns) based on whatever row is selected. It would be nice to be able to get the `PurchaseId` for the row, but not required. The way I've done this in the past is with multiple CTE's. Grabbing the `UserId, InvoiceName, MAX(PaymentDue)` then matching back on all 3 to grab the other data needed, but I'm wondering if there's a better/quicker way to accomplish this without having to use multiple cte's.

Desired result would be row 3 because it is the most recent `PaymentDue`.

EDIT:

```
PurchaseId    UserID    InvoiceName    PaymentDue    PaymentMade
    3           1       EF Fee         2016-07-26    NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding your question correctly, here's one option using `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by userid order by paymentdue desc) rn
    from #TmpTbl
    where invoicename = 'EF Fee'
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks to be working just as I need it to!

Answer (score 0):

One more approach which wont use CTE or Derived table..

```
select top 1 with ties 
PurchaseId  ,
  UserID ,
InvoiceName,
 PaymentDue,
 PaymentMade
from
table
order by 
Row_number() over (partition by userid order by purchase due desc)
```